# java.net.BindException: Address already in use while re using same connection

Tags: java, socket.io, nio

I am getting **BindException** exception while reusing same Address.Following is my code.

**in openConnection method :**

```
69.    Selector selector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
70.    SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
71.    socketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));// Edited
72.    socketChannel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
73.    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
74.    socketChannel.connect(remoteAddress);
```

**Exception:**

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.bind(SocketChannelImpl.java:580)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.bind(SocketAdaptor.java:135)
at com.example.client.request.Client.openConnection(Client.java:72)
```

> **Edit**

I solved InvalidArgument exception and I have edited the post above but now while reconnecting on same port I get the above exception.Is some thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: Calling setReuseAddress() *after* bind() is futile. It must be called before. But there is no need to call bind() at all.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, by placing setReuseAddress() above bind() solved the problem and I used bind because I want to open specific ports and reuse it.Please put your comment in answers I want to mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse an address you have to call [setReuseAddress(true)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)) before binding the socket.

Answer (score 1):

Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port. Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned.

When you start a web server or application server, which typically listen on a port e.g. Tomcat or Jetty listens on 8080 and 8084 for HTTP and HTTPS traffic, they bind a socket to a local address and port. If you give them hostname e.g. localhost or devhost, then they used /etc/host in both Windows and Linux to resolve domain name into IP address, if this mapping is incorrect than you will get java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind. This host to IP address mapping file can be found at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts, where C:\Windows is  where you have installed windows operating system. If you look at this file, you will see it contains IP address and hostname as shown below :

## 127.0.0.1 localhost

192.168.52.1 localhost

Just, correct the mapping, or add 127.0.0.1 against localhost to resolve this issue

Comment: I did try using 127.0.0.1 or localhost but that worked only till my local pc while connecting to remote it gives me InvalidArgument Exception .But Thanks for explanation I Solved it and have edited the post.